# How to deduce the charge of an electron from the charge of an oil drop in the Millikan experiment?

Tags: electricity, charge, experimental-technique, data-analysis

In the Millikan experiment we measure the charge of one oil drop. But how can I measure charge of one electron when I’m not sure how many electrons are contained within one oil drop?

Answer (score 3):

I think the key was that when you measure enough oil drops, you will notice that the charge is always a discrete multiple of some number. So it shows that charge is quantized. With enough data points, you'd see that the smallest charge difference possible is about $1.6\times 10^{-19}$ coulombs.

Answer (score 3):

Strong peaks on a graph are expected if charge is packaged in discrete
units, but not if charge is infinitely divisible.

One constructs a histogram of the charge measured, and accumulates a few thousand
data points, with very fine drops in a relatively high field.  The intent
was to only observe oil drops with small charge, such as would be held
stationary in gravity with a high E field if the droplet was of low mass.

So, if the entire range of charges measured is  1 to 20 electrons, and the
resolution of the experimental charge/mass and radius-of-droplet measurements
is sufficient, a few thousand measurements in a histogram would show
strong peaks.   The distance between the peaks is the increment of
charge corresponding to addition of one electron to a droplet.