# How can one determine the charge of $e$ in Milikan's oil drop experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, experimental-technique

Inspired from [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7047/6993) answer, I have an question about Milikan's oil drop experiment:

if we have a set of data, say $q_1, q_2, ..., q_n$, since those $g_i$'s have some error bars, we cannot directly calculate the greatest common divisor of those values because they   are not exact and it will probably lead to the result $1$, so we to find a value, say $e$, s.t for all $i$, $q_i \approx e \cdot k$, where $k$ is an integer, so without trial-and error (which would be really hard to do without computers) or any other assitant of a computer, how can we find such a value $e$ ?

**Edit:**

Considering the fact that I have asked the question [How did Milikan know that oil drops would acquire only few electron charges?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7042/how-did-milikan-know-that-oil-drops-would-acquire-only-few-electron-charges), the answer given to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327204/how-to-deduce-the-charge-of-an-electron-from-the-charge-of-an-oil-drop-in-the-mi) question is, kind of, out of range.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about statistical analysis and belongs on Cross-Validated SE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oil drop experiment and quantization of charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96254)

Comment: Have a look https://web.pa.msu.edu/courses/2003spring/PHY192/electron_charge_and_mass.pdf on the how. The milikan oil drop charge measurement is a standard physics  lab experiment . I vaguely  remember doing it back in 1959 using a microscope.

Comment: You seem to be asking "How did Millikan do it?" This is probably an historical question which those on HSM might have a better chance of answering. On the question I cited, user DWin may be able to provide some suggestions. You could leave a comment. He is still active, occasionally. Alternatively ask on Cross-Validated for a non-computer method.

Comment: There was no computer at the lab in 1959 either.  We reproduced the experiment. Pencil and paper and brain power. :) In page 10 in my link above there is a current plot measured at a student lab. in page 6 the experimental method is clearly described.

Comment: There are some basic tips on p7 [here](https://www.physics.uci.edu/~advanlab/millikan.pdf). It suggests using the smallest difference as 1st estimate of $e$. This gives the closest multiple$n$ of $e$ for each data point. Then use Linear Regression $(q=en)$ to find the value of $e$ which minimises sum of squared errors (SSE). Tweaking the biggest multiples might further reduce SSE. There is also a formula for Standard Error within Linear Regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is an example o](https://web.pa.msu.edu/courses/2003spring/PHY192/electron_charge_and_mass.pdf)f what one gets in measuring the charge with a Millikan oil drop experiment, designed for physics students at university level.

[image: miloil]

Just 12 measurements of the charge carried by the drops  are shown, already fallen into groups, as seen in this plot. When the number of measurements becomes large enough a histogram versus charge will give separate peaks .

One does not need computers, as this experiment was standard in US universities even in the 1950's, and errors and error propagation can be done by hand and brain calculations. I remember there were drops zooming fast down and drops falling slowly enough to be timed.